# Having trouble saving a document in MongoDB, Mongoose's save method not inserting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What is wrong with my usage of the mongoose package:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/messages');


var message= mongoose.Schema({
   user: String,
   message: String

});

var Message = mongoose.model('Message', message);

var message1 = new Message({user: 'diego', message: "mongoose teste"});

message1.save(function(err, message1) {
if(err) return console.error(err); else console.log("alright");
});
```

When I run the server I get "alright". But no document is inserted. Also seeing this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733647/mongoose-instance-save-not-working) a guy had this issue when specifying a wrong argument to the connect method (next to last answer).

Comment: There is no issue with your code. Its inserting data to mongodb. i checked it

Comment: note, your mongoDB collection will be `messages` not `message`, it will be pluralized

Comment: Yes, @AyushGupta, you are right. I was looking into the wrong collection. I didn't understand your comment at first because I translated my code from Portuguese to English. Original - var Mensagem = mongoose.model("Mensagem", mensagem); , the collection will be mensagems, which is grammatical error in portuguese, should be  mensagens.